# 1995 accord tie rod boot installation

Tags: honda, steering

Okay, so i have two questions. My,first question is,I posted a link to two pictures of the passenger side of the steering rack. Which position for the passenger side boot is correct? If it is picture 2 how exactly can i secure it because zip ties dont seem to be strong enough as it keeps slipping off. My second question is how exactly do i get the drivers side boot on? I have tried everything i can think of, even soaking it in some hot water and that didnt work. Any help is appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5epJi.jpg

Comment: The image link isn't working. You should edit the post and attach the photo directly to it.

Comment: Here try it now, i mightve fixed it, i tried to upload it but stack exchange said that the pic was too big

Comment: Thanks, the links are working now. Usually there are crimp clamps which come with boots when they're replaced. You can find them by searching for "cv boot clamp" on Google. They're generally pretty cheap. https://www.google.com/search?q=cv+boot+clamp I'm not sure the exact position which the boot should be in though. In the ones I've worked on, there's usually a shallow flat groove or ridge which the clamp will hold the boot into.